# How I can export the Free/Busy-Status from my Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have create this script:

```js
function myCalendar(){

  var now=new Date();
  
  var startpoint=new Date(now.getTime()-60*60*24*1000*1);
  var endpoint=new Date(now.getTime()+60*60*24*1000*10);
  
  var events=CalendarApp.getCalendarById("my.email@google.com").getEvents(startpoint, endpoint);

  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MyScedule");
  
  ss.clear();
  
  for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
         ss.getRange(i+1,1).setValue(events[i].getTitle());
         ss.getRange(i+1,2).setValue(events[i].getDescription());
         ss.getRange(i+1,3).setValue(events[i].getStartTime());
         ss.getRange(i+1,4).setValue(events[i].getEndTime());
         // HERE I WILL ADD THE FREE/BUSY-STATUS <<<<<--------------
  }
}
```

This script runs perfect. but how I can add the free/busy-status?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get the free/busy status you have to do a query to the Calendar API (***not calendarApp***) and then you will get all the events with the param BUSY. So you can default the parameter to **Free** unless the query returns **Busy**.

This is how the parameters can look like:

```
"resource": {
    "timeMax": "2020-03-15T03:30:00+05:30",
    "timeMin": "2020-01-01T03:30:00+05:30",
    "calendarExpansionMax": 3,
    "items": [
      {
        "id": "CALENDAR ID"
      }
    ]
  }
```

And this is how the response will look like:

```
 {
   "kind": "calendar#freeBusy",
   "timeMin": "2019-12-31T22:00:00.000Z",
   "timeMax": "2020-03-14T22:00:00.000Z",
   "calendars": {
    "CALENDAR ID": {
     "busy": [
      {
       "start": "2020-01-02T23:00:00Z",
       "end": "2020-01-03T23:00:00Z"
      }
     ]
    }
   }
  }
```

You can try it with your calendar here: [Freebusy: query](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query)

Comment: Thanks for you example - but it is to complex for my understanding. Is it ok for you whenn you add it into my example? So I can follow it step by step. Thanks

Comment: This is not an example of code, this is the request and return from the Freebusy: query. To see how to call the Calendar API and then do the query checkout the documentation on the Freebusy: query and the quickstart on Apps Script from Calendar API: https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/apps-script#step_1_create_the_script

Comment: Thanks for your helpful tip. No I think I have the trick. This link was the most helpful: https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/apps-script#step_1_create_the_script. Do you know where I can find a list which all searchparameters?

Comment: Yes, on the request body of the Feebusy: query -> https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query#request-body
At least you have to set the timeMin and timeMax. On the right of this page you have a try it where you can test the different parameters and see how the result returns which is what I said in the answer.